# Webpack cannot find dist/style.css

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Using webpack-dev-server, I'm able to load `./dist/index.html` at the root path (`0.0.0.0:8080`) and to view `./dist/bundle.js` at `0.0.0.0:8080/bundle.js`. I'm getting a 404 when I try to load (`0.0.0.0:8080/style.css`).

The CSS in my `./dist` directory is generated by an npm command running `node-sass`, not using webpack.

```
dist/
 - index.html
 - bundle.js
 - style.css
```

### webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require('path');
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: "./src/index.ts",
      mode: "development",
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: "ts-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // instead of style-loader
              'css-loader'
            ]
          },
        ],
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
      },
      plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
          { 
            filename: './style.css' 
            //also tried: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist", "style.css") 
          }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"),
          inject: false
        })
      ],
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
      },
    };
```

(from https://blog.jakoblind.no/css-modules-webpack/)

What should I add or change so that my browser can reach the CSS file at `./dist/style.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` doesn't actually store files on disk, it just makes them on the fly and then holds them in memory to answer http requests. So by default, it won't know about anything in `dist`; it only knows how/where to serve files that it can also generate.

However, you can configure it to serve additional existing files from disk (and watch them for changes), by adding this to your webpack config. In Webpack 5:

```js
devServer: {
  static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

In Webpack 4 it was called `contentBase`:

```js
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  watchContentBase: true
}
```

Comment: I wish I knew why HtmlWebpackPlugin appears capable of loading `dist/index.html` without needing to add a `devServer` object.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Webpack 5, where support for `devServer.contentBase` has been removed. With your suggestion I was able to get it working using `devServer { static: { directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') } }`. I'm just guessing that `static` is the new `contentBase`.

Comment: That's because the path to it is given explicitly in the HtmlWebpackPlugin config there: `path.resolve(__dirname, "dist", "index.html")`. Any old path could be used there, it just happens to be `dist/index.html`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it was renamed in webpack 5, nice work! I'll edit the answer.